# Cannot read property '$moment' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, momentjs, nuxt.js

i was added nuxt moment on module nuxt.config.js and i try to call moment on mounted() a page but has undefined $moment.

nuxt.config.js

```
modules: [
    ...
    '@nuxtjs/moment',
    ...
  ],
```

pages

```
mounted() {
    console.log(this.$moment) // undefined $moment
  },
```

what wrong with this?

Answer (score 1):

My configuration in nuxt.config.js:

```
...

modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/moment',
    ['@nuxtjs/moment', { tdefaultLocale: 'en',
    locales: ['en'] }]
]

...
```

Then use it like this on any page:

```
<span> {{$moment(timestamp_var).format('ddd DD MMM') }} </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

just install moment by using below command

> npm install moment

Comment: I was installed moment js on my project